# How should be the version tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Make it sense to create tags there also include blender as a part of the tag e.g

> blender-2.67

Is not be easier/more DRY to create only tags for the version number like `2. 67` because we are here in the blender stack exchange.

What you think?

Comment: Hey! You guys are talking about me! I did that!

Comment: We're don't talk about you but about the future of the version tags. You were only the initiator of the question. :D

Answer (score 11):

I propose that there be two (maybe three) levels of specificity. For instance:

- [blender-1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-1) vs [blender-2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-2) (likely will rarely be used, if at all)
- [blender-2.4](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-2.4) vs [blender-2.6](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-2.6) (huge changes in interface, inner structure, etc)
- [blender-2.66](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-2.66) vs [blender-2.67](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-2.67) (new features present in one version and not earlier versions)

I would say that when tagging a question, the more general, the better. For example, if you can do the same thing in 2.4 as in 2.6, then it makes little sense to tag as 2.67. Perhaps we could also use tags such as [blender-2.4+](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-2.4%2b) for questions where an answer exists in 2.4 and up as a way of clarifying that the question isn't about 2.4 *only*, so answers in 2.6 would be fine as well.

One thing's for certain though: there is no use in having a [blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender) tag. It adds no value to any question. I'm currently a mod on Christianity.SE and the tag "christianity" doesn't exist because there's no point in having it.

Comment: The problem with this is that you will have many many tags.

Comment: @PhoneixS: It's better to have many specific tags than a few too-broad tags.

Comment: Yes, if we will have version tags, they must be for specific version (2.66). And thinking again about it, well, there isn't so many new releases.

Comment: The site is about Blender, let the questions specify the version.

Comment: I agree. Must be specific version tags. This matters a lot when talking about bugs.

Comment: I agree that `blender` should not be a valid tag within the scope of this forum.

Comment: Should we just shorten it to `2.67` instead of `blender-2.67` ?

Comment: @DantheMan: There is potential for confusion that way. After all, Cycles, Yafaray, and other programs also have their own version numbers.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman Ok. Good point.

Comment: Having version tags has worked well for us on Ask Ubuntu. Sometimes there are issues and questions specific to a single version, and it is useful to separate these out with a tag.

Answer (score 3):

I'd encourage the use of either a blender prefix or a version prefix in order to make it clear what it is that number refers to. It might be obvious to many but the clarity would be improved even if it's less DRY.

Comment: +1 for version prefix

Answer (score 3):

I think we should only have one tag, something like [versions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/versions) or [builds](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/builds), which would be used for questions relating to different versions of blender.

**Some examples of existing questions which could use this tag:**

[Mesh appears normal in solid mode but looks weird in textured mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2626/mesh-appears-normal-in-solid-mode-but-looks-weird-in-textured-mode/2627#2627)

[Blender release life cycle and versioning](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/blender-release-life-cycle-and-versioning)

Such a tag could also be used for upgrade questions such as this one:
[Is there a way to update Blender without deleting it and downloading the new version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269/is-there-a-way-to-update-blender-without-deleting-it-and-downloading-the-new-ver)

This might be a stretch, but this question might also be eligible for such a tag:
[Working with VRML 1.0 files in the current version of Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2587/working-with-vrml-1-0-files-in-the-current-version-of-blender)

I feel that having many tags for specific releases of blender is overkill when most questions are only related to the current version, but there are enough questions that are related to versions of blender that such a tag could make sense.

Comment: Blender _versions_ are actually stable _builds_ for the most part. I say one tag is enough, the `builds` tag should cover any of these questions. `versions` is a very vague version of what OP and [El'endia Starman suggested](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/11/12).

Comment: @iKlsR They could be synonimized, but I think it would be good to at least have a prompt for whatever tag we use if a user starts typing `versions` or `releases`

Comment: Good note, I will make this so.

Comment: The problem with doing this for questions about different versions is that, as time goes on, a build that was up-to-date will become out-of-date, and a build that was beta will become the release-- but nobody will constantly update tags of all questions.

Answer (score 1):

This would be extremely messy, if such a tag were to exist, it would be one set tag such as [blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender) and that alone. *If* a question is tied to a specific version it can be specified in the question and or answer.

That being said, I am against such a tag as it would make little if any sense or even be of any use as the site ***is*** about Blender and presumably and preferably, the questions will be too.

Comment: I agree, keep it simple and tag with only [tag:blender]

Comment: Seconded. Having version-specific tags is too messy.

Comment: @iKlsR: I'm not sure if you're arguing for or against a plain [tag:blender] tag. Can you clarify?

Comment: @El'endiaStarman The first paragraph I was evaluating what could happen if one were to be used and the second I clearly say why it makes no sense. I have edited it to be a bit clearer.

Comment: @iKlsR I agree that this would be quite messy, but I think there would be a use for a single tag. (though maybe call it something more meaningful than [tag:blender]) See [my answer](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/272/599)