# Was the 'blender-2.8' tag created intentionally or should we remove it?

Tags: discussion, tags

A [blender-2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-2.8) tag seems to have cropped up recently on the main site. As it seems to have been [somewhat discussed](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2546/should-we-ask-users-to-indicate-what-version-of-blender-theyre-using) that we won't have tags for different versions (or at least, there's [no real consensus](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/how-should-be-the-version-tags) of what they should be), should this tag be removed from any questions it's on or did I miss the discussion where it was decided it should be created?

*(If so, do we edit the questions manually to remove the tag or do the mods have some ability to batch remove?)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider these removed and the tag blacklisted, not sure how this slipped by for so long. Let this be the real consensus. It has been discussed time and time again, time to cement it.

Comment: The iKlsR has spoken. Version tags are a #sadmess

Comment: Without a complete API and implementation I'm surprised anyone is asking any assistance for it since a lot will ultimately change. A lot of the questions will have to specify Alpha/ Beta. But, as a side note Eevee is really really awesome.